# Running 32-bit code in 64-bit process on Linux - memory access

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm experimenting with running 32-bit code inside a 64-bit Linux process. The 32-bit code is completely self-contained, it makes direct IA32 system calls on its own. If I were to load this code in a 32-bit process, it would run just fine.

Initially, I thought I could just allocate a stack for the 32-bit code, switch to it and everything would work fine, but that didn't go so well. Mainly because stack-related instructions (POP/PUSH/...) were doing 8-byte shifts instead of 4 bytes.

By googling, I learned that I can transition to 32-bit mode by switching to segment selector 0x23. Unfortunately, segments are something I know very little about.

I am able to transition to 32-bit mode with something like this (inline AT&T assembly):

```
movl $0x23, 4(%%rsp) // segment selector 0x23
movq %0, %%rax
movl %%eax, (%%rsp) // target 32-bit address to jump to
lret
```

Where %0 contains a 32-bit address of where the code is mapped. The code starts running, I can see that PUSH/POP now works the way it should, but it crashes even earlier than when I ran the code in 64-bit mode on a seemingly innocuous instruction:

```
0x8fe48201      mov    0xa483c(%rbx),%ecx
```

Where `%rbx` (or more like `%ebx` since this code is already 32-bit, GDB just doesn't know that) contains `0x8fe48200`. The address it's trying to read from (`0x8feeca3c`) is valid and readable (according to `/proc/XXX/maps`) and when I read it from within GDB, it contains the expect value.

Yet, Linux sends a `SIGSEGV` to the process on this instruction and the faulting address is `0` (as reported by `strace` or `p $_siginfo._sifields._sigfault.si_addr` inside `gdb`). Somehow it seems `0x8feeca3c` is not a valid address in the 32-bit realm.

Any ideas how to proceed?

UPDATE: I have written a minimal example that segfaults reading address 0, although address 0 is not really being referenced. It seems that reading any addresses in memory fails (even reading the address of the instruction that has just been executed!), although stack operations work OK.

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// 32-bit code we're executing
const unsigned char instructions[] = {
        0x6a, 0, // push 0
        0x58, // popl %eax
        0xe8, 0, 0, 0, 0, // call the next line to get our location in memory
        0x5b, // pop %ebx
        // THE FOLLOWING mov SEGFAULTS, but it is well within the mapped area (which has size 0x3000)
        // A simpler "mov (%ebx), %eax" (0x8b, 0x03) would fail as well
        0x8b, 0x83, 0, 0x20, 0, 0, // mov 0x2000(%ebx), %eax
        0xf4 // hlt, not reached
};

int main()
{
        void* area;
        void* stack;

        area = mmap(NULL, 3*4096, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_32BIT, -1, 0);
        memcpy(area, instructions, sizeof(instructions));

        stack = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_32BIT, -1, 0);
        stack = (void*) (((uint64_t) stack) + 4096 - 4);

        memset(((char*)area) + 2*4096, 0xab, 100); // Place 0xAB in the area we mov from in 32-bit instructions

        // Switch to 32-bit mode and jump into the code
        __asm__ volatile("movq %1, %%rsp;" \
                         "subq $8, %%rsp;" \
                         "movl $0x23, 4(%%rsp);" \
                         "movq %0, %%rax;" \
                         "movl %%eax, (%%rsp);" \
                         "lret" :: "m"(area), "r"(stack) :);
}
```

Comment: Try to narrow it down to a [mcve]. Verify the memory for the instruction is executable. Also, look in syslog, that sometimes has information.

Comment: Yes, the instruction is executable. I've added a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question :)

The problem is that `ds` is still set to zero, in 64 bit mode it's not used. So, you need to reload that and it will work. Changing your initial test push/pop to `push $0x2b; pop %ds` will do the trick:

```
const unsigned char instructions[] = {
        0x6a, 0x2b, // push $0x2b
        0x1f, // pop %ds
```

I extracted the `0x2b` value from a 32 bit program. I just kept wondering why `push` worked. On closer look, `ss` is set in 64 bit mode too, so it may be safer to copy that to `ds` as well as to `es`.

Comment: Ha, just figured out that DS plays an important role at the same time as you wrote the answer :-D Although I did something a little different: mov $0x23, %ax; mov %ax, %ds Which seems to work too, but I'm not sure what the difference between 0x23 and 0x2B is. Any idea?

Comment: `0x23` is a code selector, it may not be writable, although in practice it seems to be.

Comment: You're right, I couldn't write into the stack directly with `0x23`, `0x2b` works. Thanks!